# How to implement X-Forwarded-For to see header in web page

Tags: x-forwarded-for

I am wanting to implement X-Forwarded-For so that when a user visits a site the actual IP is registered. So far I have added the following to my apache.conf file on my load balancer:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %{X-Forwarded-For}i" common
CustomLog /var/log/custom.log common
```

This has resulted in a customer log being created in /var/logs. This is a start however I want to be able to get the IP when a user visits the site and log this to the database. This will be done on the ruby side but I had expected that when you inspect an element on the site (eg chrome inspect) you can see x-forwarded-for in the header section. At present I have a number of response and request headers but no x-forwarded-for.

Any suggestions or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Is the Apache system behind the a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

x-forward-for is an inbound http header (like HTTP HOST) used by reverse proxises and load balances to give you a list of servers, similar to the received by header in SMTP, each hop adds an IP.

3rd parties like CloudFlare, Akamai, Incapsula will use their own variant of this such as Client-IP as premise systems (like load balancesrs ) will use x-forward-for.  Many of the above also provide plugins to provide apps (like wordpress) with the real ip address.

Your question seems more geared to how to program ruby to read this information, which is a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124292/how-to-log-real-client-ip-in-rails-log-when-behind-proxy-like-nginx) question.

Comment: You're right but in terms of the server how do i enable X-Forwarded-For so it can be picked up by the application code. I know how to add it to a log but how do i ensure that it is passed as a header so that the application code can pick it up.